# How to find symbol(s) at or near a given memory address ? (using Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, memory, symbols

While debugging Windows application, I wanted to find out if it is possible to locate symbols at a given memory location (and how). This will be the reverse operation of typing a symbol in the "Memory" window, which will translate the symbol to its address. But not the other way around.

It is super easy on VxWorks shell, and possible with Linux gdb. Should be possible on VS.

Thanks.

Comment: You would think... :(  You will have to use DIA manually to find that information out.  Please file a suggestion here: http://connect.microsoft.com/

Comment: Thanks. Will do that.What is DIA ?

Comment: DIA is an API for querying the symbols files, `pdb`, that are generated during build.  This is not a trivial task.  Search for "DIA SDK"

Comment: OK. Doesn't look too bad. I located the SDK already on my hard disk (which was not obvious). After compiling and running the sample app, Dia2dump.exe, I was able to see the symbol map from a .pdb. Of course now I will have to manually search for each address, but that's still better than nothing. I don't understand why such useful functionality is so much hidden and obfuscated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using windbg to debug, command "ln Address" will help you check the symbols near the target address, hope that will help you.

Answer (score 8):

If you are lucky and you know the exact address, but do not know the symbol name,
try to write the address into the Watch window, and the VS will find the symbol.
E.g.

```
(void *)0x6F63E248  -> 0x6f63e248 {My.dll!TMyString<char,CMyMemHeap>  *s_psMyAppNameAbbr}   void *
```

Comment: +1 As long as the question is "How to find symbol at a given memory address?", this is a valid and useful answer.

Comment: This was very useful, exactly what I needed.